# Lumen - FatalThrowableError Call to a member function file() on null

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am trying to insert values into my file table and I am getting a error. FatalThrowableError Call to a member function file() on null.

Inset.php Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Inset extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'insets';

    public function file()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\File');
    }
}
```

File.php Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class File extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'files';
    protected $fillable = ['file_name','file_content', 'insets_post'];

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function inpost()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Inpost');
    }
}
```

FilesController.php Controller

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Kacper
 * Date: 28.02.2018
 * Time: 14:00
 */

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\File;
use App\Inset;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;

class FilesController
{
    public function showAll(Request $request)
    {
        return File::all();
    }

    public function show($ID_inset)
    {
        return File::findOrFail($ID_inset);
    }

    public function insert(Request $request)
    {
        $inset = Inset::find($request->input('inset_id'));
        $file =$inset ->file()->create([
            'file_name' => $request->input('file_name'),
            'file_content' => Crypt::encrypt($request->input('file_content'))
        ]);
        $file->save();
    }
}
```

Error:

> (1/1) FatalThrowableError Call to a member function file() on null
>
> in FilesController.php (line 31) at
>   FilesController->insert(object(Request)) at
>   call_user_func_array(array(object(FilesController), 'insert'),
>   array(object(Request))) in BoundMethod.php (line 29) at
>   BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container{closure}() in BoundMethod.php (line
>   87) at BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(object(Application),
>   array(object(FilesController), 'insert'), object(Closure)) in
>   BoundMethod.php (line 31) at BoundMethod::call(object(Application),
>   array(object(FilesController), 'insert'), array(), null) in
>   Container.php (line 564) at
>   Container->call(array(object(FilesController), 'insert'), array()) in
>   RoutesRequests.php (line 373) at
>   Application->callControllerCallable(array(object(FilesController),
>   'insert'), array()) in RoutesRequests.php (line 316) at
>   Application->callControllerAction(array(true, array('uses' =>
>   'App\Http\Controllers\FilesController@insert'), array())) in
>   RoutesRequests.php (line 275) at
>   Application->callActionOnArrayBasedRoute(array(true, array('uses' =>
>   'App\Http\Controllers\FilesController@insert'), array())) in
>   RoutesRequests.php (line 260) at
>   Application->handleFoundRoute(array(true, array('uses' =>
>   'App\Http\Controllers\FilesController@insert'), array())) in
>   RoutesRequests.php (line 160) at
>   Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns{closure}() in RoutesRequests.php
>   (line 413) at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array(),
>   object(Closure)) in RoutesRequests.php (line 166) at
>   Application->dispatch(null) in RoutesRequests.php (line 107) at
>   Application->run() in index.php (line 28)

Comment: Well you have to check if `$inset` isn't null before executing its `file` function.

Comment: thanks it's work :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Code

```
$inset = Inset::find($request->input('inset_id'));
```

Is returning null that's why it is Throwing this error.

if you want to avoid error you can do this like

```
$inset = Inset::find($request->input('inset_id'));

 if($inset){
    $file =$inset ->file()->create([
        'file_name' => $request->input('file_name'),
        'file_content' => Crypt::encrypt($request->input('file_content'))
    ]);
    $file->save();
 }
```

Hope this helps